# Why does Symfony's Mailer not send email?

Tags: symfony, symfony-mailer

I am sending email for password reset. Unfortunately I am not able to send email. Here is my .env configuration. I have tried with Gmail configuration using Gmail mailer but failed.

Email configuration of server are as: Incoming mail: mail.app.iasisting.ro. Outgoing mail: mail.app.iasisting.ro. SMTP port: 465

Symfony's Mailer

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://info%40app.iasisting.ro:xy7bfdtIYt0h@mail.app.iasisting.ro:465/?encryption=ssl
```

Symfony's Mailer giving me `null` value. Any help to send email to user account.